# Integration Testing AngularJS + Karma + Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, testing, karma-jasmine

I would like to test my `angular service` I would like to test it with real data - a.k.a (Integration Test). I'm using Jasmine and Karma.

Here is my test:

```
describe('Trending Data Service', function () {
  var value = 0, originalTimeout = 0;
  var service, Enums, $httpBackend;

  // initialize module
  beforeEach(module('waterfall'));

  // initialize services
  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
    service = $injector.get("trendingService");
    Enums = $injector.get("Enums");
    spyOn(service, 'fetch').and.callThrough();
  }));

  it('check if dependencies are defined', function () {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
    expect(Enums).toBeDefined();
    expect(service.categories).toBeDefined();
    expect(service.fetch).toBeDefined();
  });

  it('categories array should be defined within the service', function () {
    expect(service.categories.length).toEqual(9);
    expect(service.categories).toEqual(jasmine.any(Array));
  });

  // this test is alway fails...
  it('fetch method should return initial result', function (done) {
    var promise = service.fetch(Enums.socials.viewAll, false);

    promise.then(function (result) {
      done();
    }, function() {
      expect(1).toBe(2);
      done.fail('Error occured');
    });
  });
}
```

This is the error:
`Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

I tried a wide range of solutions and I haven't got any success with this.

**EDIT: 29/April/2016**

```
var trendingService = function ($q, $http) {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   var $this = this;
   this.fetch = function (id) {
       $http.get(url).then(function (result) {
          deferred.resolve(result);
       }).catch(function(err) {
          deferred.reject(err);
       });
       return deferred.promise;
   }
   return {
      fetch: $this.fetch;
   };
};

var Enums = {
   Roles: {
      Admin: 1,
      User: 2,
      NotRegistered: 0
   }
};

angular.module('').const('Enums', Enums);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karma isn't meant for integration testing. Your call to module('waterfall') is actually a reference to angular.mock.module which mocks all $https calls.

You need to use some form of end-to-end testing to test with real data. I suggest http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/.

Comment: I agree, you could also look at http://www.seleniumhq.org/ for browser-based regression automation suites and tests

Comment: How does it helps if I want to check my concrete service without going e2e? I don't want to know if the concrete data is bound. I want to know that data is there and bound to specific logic within the concrete service. Like I do in C# testing.